# Why is my React query in Next.js with tanstack/react-query still making API requests before the staleTime is up?

Tags: next.js, react-query, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

Im testing react-query and SSR from nextjs to prefetch data only when the staleTime is gone. But after testing it, every 20 seconds a new get request is done to the API, even if the the staleTime is more than 20 seconds. I don't really understand why. This is the code:

**Index**:

```js
import { dehydrate, QueryClient, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Image from "next/image";
import axios from "axios";

type SpaceXData = {
  name: string;
  links: {
    patch: {
      large: string;
    };
  };
};

const getSpaceXData = async () =>
  await (
    await axios("https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/latest")
  ).data;

export default function Page() {
  const { data } = useQuery<SpaceXData>(["spacex"], getSpaceXData);

  console.log(data);

  if (!data) return <h1>Error</h1>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <Image
        src={data.links.patch.large}
        alt="image"
        width={500}
        height={500}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery(["spacex"], getSpaceXData, {
    staleTime: 30000,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  };
}
```

_app.tsx:

```js
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import {
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
  Hydrate,
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import React from "react";

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const queryClient = React.useRef(
    new QueryClient({
      defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
          refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
          retry: false, staleTime: 30000,

        },
      },
    })
  );

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient.current}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Hydrate>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

With react-query devtools I can see that the data only becomes stales after 30 seconds, but in between those 30 seconds a request is done and the other are all cache requests. I have tried to put a timeout on the axios request but the behaviour is the same. Maybe its because I have two query-clients or maybe is the SSR from next that is doing the revalidation.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding the Question, but it sounds like you're seeing the fetches on the server, when you navigate between pages? Note that `getStaticProps` is called [for every request in development mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props#runs-on-every-request-in-development).

With server side rendering, we have to distinguish between two scenarios:

1. a fetch happens on the server. This is your `getStaticProps`.
2. a fetch happens on the client. This would be re-fetches triggered by react-query, or because a new useQuery instance mounts etc.

The QueryCache lives inside the QueryClient, which is why you create one in an instance ref in your `_app.tsx`. This QueryClient will be available on the client / browser - only for scenario 2)

This is also the QueryClient that gets data **hydrated** from the server when the page first renders.

But on the server, inside `getStaticProps`, the queryClient is newly created every time:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

await queryClient.prefetchQuery(["spacex"], getSpaceXData, {
  staleTime: 30000,
});
```

this means when you make that prefetch, the cache inside that client is empty (so putting `staleTime` there doesn't achieve much).

So, what you would need to de-duplicate those requests as well is some sort of server-side caching. If you put the queryClient outside of `getStaticProps`, it would live in-memory on the server, but data would be shared between all users, which is why it's not encouraged. Server-side caching is a completely different sort of caching, you could think about storing the result of the QueryClient in redis and re-using it, but it's usually not worth it. Especially because `getStaticProps` is only called on every request in dev mode, not in production. This is more of a `getServerSideProps` problem.